# Injective objects in an abelian category and split exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

It's known that a module $Q$ is injective if and only if every short exact $0 \to Q \to M \to P \to 0$ splits, and I'm wondering if this holds true for general abelian categories.

Comment: It is true. You can prove it using the fact that pushouts of monomorphisms are monomorphisms in abelian categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin can you provide a proof using CD's  (https://q.uiver.app) in an answer?